# Intermittent slowness Spring Webflux application deployed on tomcat 8.5.5

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, tomcat8.5

We are using tomcat 8.5.5 to deploy the spring webflux application,
When making Get Rest call to service then it makes select on MongoDB and returns Flux.

Frequently it's giving a slow response sometimes return in 1-2 seconds, but sometimes it took around 1 minute.

I am not getting any errors in the logs.

Comment: Tomcat doesnt support reactive so you only get emulated reactiveness, which means use of the Async Servlet API and that is it. So you are basically still using the servlet api underneath with all the limitations. Spring Boot exposes a task executor with a limited number of threads, you might need to increase the number of threads for that one (those are under the `spring.task` namespace.

Comment: Having similar issue, any lead on this ?